# Is there any static code analysis tool for Spock tests in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, continuous-integration, spock

**Question**

I'd like to use in my CI pipeline some tool to verify code standards for Spock tests in Groovy. I have looked at archunit, codenarc and sonarcube but didn't find rules for *Spock tests written in Groovy*. Do you know any such a tool?

**Example**

There is example of code standard that must be verified by the tool. The test below always passes, however condition `true == false` is evaluated to `false`. This happend due to bad usage of `helperMethod()` is Spock. You could read more about helper methods in [documentation](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_helper_methods).

```
def "test that always passes"(){
    when:
    1 + 1

    then:
    helperMethod()
}

def helperMethod(){
    true == false // evaluated to false
    true == true
}
```

I need to verify that developer didn't forget to add assertions in the helper method by using `assert`, `&&` or `verifyAll`. Below are valid examples of helper method

```
def helperMethod1() {
    assert true == false
    assert true == true
}

def helperMethod2() {
    true == false
    && true == true
}

def helperMethod3() {
    verifyAll {
        true == false
        true == true
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently no there isn't. There's a request over here https://github.com/CodeNarc/CodeNarc/issues/261#issuecomment-498763705 but I've not seen anything come of it

Comment: I would suggest to do code reviews, as tools can only do so much.